# sql date select

Tags: sql, date

I want to write a select statement to find a date from my database.

In the database I have a field `action_date` as a date type with dates like this: `7/12/2012 17:21:33`.
How do I get all data from after the specified date?

So if I have db like this:

```
7/12/2012 17:21:33
7/12/2012 15:21:35
8/12/2012 8:25:35
9/12/2014 8:25:35
```

I want get only these rows:

```
7/12/2012 17:21:33
7/12/2012 15:21:35
```

Comment: what database software are you using

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: And what does "from after the specified date" mean? Which is that specified date? Why are the rows from Dec 12 2012 and Dev 9 2014 not listed, while these dates are obviously **after** that given date Dev 7 2012?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select * from
yourtable where yourDateColumn < '2012-12-8' and yourDateColumn >= '2012-12-07'
```

Comment: maybe "yourDateColumn >= '2012-12-07'" is better if you want to catch midnight also

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BETWEEN` to compare the dates:

```
select *
from yourTable
where yourDate between '2012-07-12' and '2012-08-12'
```

Or if you are looking for one date in particular you can use. You can change the '2012-07-12' to a parameter that could be passed in so you could get any date:

```
select *
from yourTable
where Cast(datediff(day, 0, yourDate) as datetime) = '2012-07-12'
```

Comment: The question is asking about a single day; you are providing data for a month and a day.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler edited, to include if they only want one day to be returned.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the Julius is asking how to get only rows with 7/12/2012 17:21:33

So I can offer you one solution that is proven to be right:

1) Take a look at T-SQL Convert function at [T-SQL Convert function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

2) When you will look at that take note on conversion codes

[image: Convert codes]

*Image source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx*

And now when I annoyed everybody with the theory here is the code:

**For europe**

```
select * from table_name
where convert(varchar, column_that_has_date_in, 104) = '12.07.2012'
```

**For US**

```
select * from table_name
where convert(varchar, column_that_has_date_in, 101) = '07/12/2012'
```

And one other thing worth mentioning is why when we type in sql statement we get 0 rows:

```
select * from table_name
where column_that_has_date_in like '%07/12/2012%'
```

**This is because the query is looking only for dates with NO TIME portion.**

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT SUM(your_value)  
FROM your_Table 
where value(Date) BETWEEN '2018/04/14' AND '2018/04/14';
```

Comment: In which SQL dialect is `value(Date)` a valid syntax and what does it do? And how does that `between` / `and` works if both dates are the same as you show?

Comment: SELECT your_value
  FROM [table]
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018/04/14' AND '2018/04/14';

Comment: There is an [edit] link so you can fix or add details to your answer. It helps if you don't only dump code but also explain what it does and why your statement is to be preferred opposed to the other answers.